# Fancybox 2.0.6 - AfterClose fires before fancybox opens

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox 2.0.6 and jQuery 1.7.2.

I have an asp.net web page with two update panels, one on the left and one on the right. In the left one there is a Telerik RadTreeList control with a questionnaire structure, selecting a question updates the right panel with the specifics of that question.

There is also a button (called ActionButton, outside the update panels) that triggers a server-side event to generate an id for the answer to the question.
The event then updates a hidden link with the answer id, and triggers a fancybox by setting a hidden Literal to Visible.

```
<a href="action.aspx" id="hidden_link" class="actionbutton" style="visibility: hidden;" runat="server"></a>
<asp:Button ID="btnAction" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnOpenAction" CssClass="formbuttons" OnClick="btnAction_Click" />
<asp:Literal runat="server" Visible="false" ID="Literal1" Text="<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>jQuery(document).ready(function () { $('#MainContent_hidden_link').trigger('click'); });</script>" />
```

The fancybox is an iFrame that contains another web page that saves further details to the database.
So far, so good. Everything works as expected. But, what I want to do now is update the left update panel to show that details have been added.

Here's the fancybox code:

```
        $("a.actionbutton").fancybox({
            'type': 'iframe',
            'openEffect': 'elastic',
            'closeEffect': 'elastic',
            'openSpeed': 600,
            'closeSpeed': 200,
            'padding': 10,
            'width': 800,
            'height': 600,
            afterClose: function () {
                $('#ctl00$MainContent$btnHiddenAction').trigger('click');
                alert('Ha!'); 
            }
        });
```

I'm going nuts here as I can't get the afterClose callback to fire *after* closing. I get my "Ha!" alert as soon as I click the ActionButton, and after clicking OK on that, the fancybox pops up. I've tried using beforeClose but it doesn't fire at all.

When pasting my code into [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTBvV/89/) it works as it should?!?

What am I doing wrong? Help me before the guys with the long-armed shirts come along...

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Please provide the generated html code so we can debug the front-end parts which are relevant to fancybox?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ignoring the afterClose event completely.

Instead I added a javascript call in the close script for the fancybox, at the bottom of  the action.aspx page shown in the fancybox:

```
</body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    function CloseMe() { parent.$.fancybox.close(); parent.document.getElementById('ctl00$MainContent$btnHiddenAction').click(); }</script>
</html>
```

It works for me, maybe it's a help to someone else out there... :)